# SQL Select Statement LIKE 'T%'

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to run a SELECT Query that pulls the Last Names that begin with T. When I run it I just get 0 results but there are names in the table that do begin with the letter T.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my Code

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, City
FROM Customers
WHERE LastName LIKE 'T%';
```

Comment: Your query is correct, please check again whether you have correct data inside your table. Post your snapshot of table structure and data if you can't find the problem.

Comment: Check for leading spaces in `LastName` column values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause for this is that you have leading spaces in `LastName` column values.

To find all entries that have at least one leading space

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, City
  FROM Customers
 WHERE LastName LIKE ' %';
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d292/2)** demo

To fix such entries you can do

```
UPDATE Customers
   SET LastName = TRIM(LastName)
 WHERE LastName LIKE ' %';
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/371f8/1)** demo